# My Sinatra App displaying 'Internal Server Error' after deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby, deployment, heroku

My app is working locally, But after deploying to Heroku I'm getting an 'Internal Server Error' on my page

The Error log is as follows.

http://pastie.org/private/b5lgfmij1by3krieyp9sq

I cannot see what the problem is

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Clearly your problem is at line 81 in main.rb - it would be helpful if you could post that block of code :P

Comment: Did you migrate the database on Heroku?

Comment: Sharing some code is always a good practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to your database (or lack of):

`2013-05-13T06:58:57.488018+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error - could not connect to server: Connection refused`

Did you add one with `$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:[dev|basic|crane|etc] -a app_name`? Checkout this Dev Center article with info on setting up Rack based web apps (including Sinatra) and setting up database access:

- [Deploying Rack-based Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack)

Comment: oh right, I didn't migrate my database at all. I guess I initially followed the 'generic' instructions for deploying a Sinatra app. I will re-try with the database and see what happens. THANKS A LOT FOR THE HELP!!